# Only allow one of two columns to be set

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a constraint in an SQL table that will only allow one of two nullable columns to be set per row. Both columns are foreign keys that relate to different tables.

As an example, say each table row describes a section of a journey. I have a separate table for `Cars` and `Planes`.

Without redesigning my whole database to use a `Vehicles` table, how can I ensure that each journey row is done by ***either*** a `CarID` or a `PlaneID`, but never both at the same time, and never neither?

Comment: Redesign to use vehicles, you know it makes sense!

Comment: Hehe, it does, but unfortunately time is just not on my side. I'll have to convince the management to give me some refactoring time!

Comment: I'm telling the normalisation police!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constraint something like this...

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Nullable CHECK (
                                    (CarID IS NULL AND PlaneID IS NOT NULL)
                                   OR 
                                    (CarID IS NOT NULL AND PlaneID IS NULL)
                                 )
```